# ASP.NET webservices slow on first call?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have an asp.net V4 website that have lot of Jquery Ajax calls. I am making them via exposing asp.net webservices methods.

My problem is that always the first call to the service is very slow (almost 10s) then its fast and normal. I read many articles but non of them provided a significant change.

FYI, i am using the website locally without proxy.

1. What are best practices to follow.
2. is using the new .net Web API will make it better.

Comment: FYI, you are using the old ASMX web service technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: you have the same problem as [everyone else](https://www.google.dk/search?q=iis+app+pool+slow+first&oq=iis+app+pool+slow+first) that uses IIS. When the application pool sleeps, takes a while to re start again.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sometimes you don't need all the overhead of WCF and Web API, for example if you just need to make a few tiny services available, like if you are using the [Auto Complete Extender from the AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

Comment: What makes you think there's much overhead with WCF and `basicHttpBinding`? And then there's the matter of _support_. Microsoft are not fixing ASMX bugs.

Comment: WCF requires learning a new architecture, and is several more layers than a simple ASMX file. If the service is working fine now, then there may not be any solid reason to upgrade to WCF. You don't really need _support_ if it's working fine now.

Comment: Again, "several more layers" doesn't mean it doesn't perform as well. Considering that WCF is being maintained, and that ASMX is not being maintained, and that WCF has been the replacement for ASMX since 2006, it may be time to consider learning the new architecture.  Which, BTW, there's not much to learn if you stick to a one to  one replacement for ASMX.

Answer (score 0):

A while back you would wake the app pool using a ping like technique that requested a resource that would cause the application to come alive, or keep-alive. The timing and movement of assets caused a lot of heartache with ping like techniques.

There is a new setting in IIS that will re-invoke an app pool after its time out. The functionality is built into an IIS add-on so less effort is needed to manage and configure.

Please take a look at Rick Strahl's web article on this topic [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/02/Use-IIS-Application-Initialization-for-keeping-ASPNET-Apps-alive).

Comment: While the linked article may well answer the question, link-only answers are frowned upon on [so]. Please edit your question to include the gist of the linked article. That way, if the link breaks some day, your answer will still have value.

Comment: Edited with a brief overview.